# Отображение картинки веб-сервером python

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Необходимо реализовать локальный веб сервер на python. Для этого была использована библиотека BaseHTTPServer. Все работает вроде бы нормально, но возникает проблема при открытии картинок. Они либо просто не открываются, либо отображаются некорректно. Хотя в хэдере устанавливаю Content-type :image/jpeg. Пример кода, где считываю картинку:

```
ext = self.path.split('.')[-1]
self.send_response(200)
f = open(curdir+sep+self.path, 'U')
self.send_response(200)
self.send_header("Content-type", "image/jpeg")
self.end_headers()
self.wfile.write(f.read())
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы открыли изображение в текстовом режиме, а надо в бинарном.

```
f = open(curdir+sep+self.path, 'rb')
```

[Поиск рулит](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287219/how-do-i-serve-image-content-types-with-python-basehttpserverrequesthandler-do-g)

Comment: Спасибо! просто я почему-то не нашел в документации бинарный режим.

Comment: @perseids_starfall Проблема актуальна только для виндов. В юниксоподобных: юниксы, линукс, MAC OS X "текстового режима" a la ms dos нет.

Comment: @alexlz Что такое текстовый режим a la ms dos? Я так думал, что текстовый режим - соглашение об интерпритации некоторых байтов.

Comment: Ага. Последовательности <CR><LF> на носителе соответствуют <LF> в программе. (`\r\n` -- `\n`). CTRL-Z -- конец файла. Пришло из ms dos (или даже её предка CP/M). В юникслайках байты передаются без преобразований и интерпретации CTRL-Z. (Вообще форматы файлов бывают гораздо более причудливыми -- см. RMS из VMS-11 или некоторых os для pdp-11). Разработчики unix такими вопросами не заморачивались.

Comment: @alexlz То-то я ни разу об этом не задумывался! :) На линуксе сижу